# Entrypoint on webapp allows semi-arbitrary data to be written. Can it be considered as DoS?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability, denial-of-service, cve

My team and I have written a web app, and we had a bug report regarding a DoS vulnerability.

This vulnerability, requires a basic account to be created and allows this user to inject semi-arbitrary data `mydata-XXX-mydata` where `XXX` is controlled by the attacker.
This data is not supposed to be controlled by the user and allows DB inserts,
as many as the user requests them. The reported bug uses a bypass technic to allow this data to be altered.

We do believe that it could slow down/fill-up the DB (and probably disk space). Can it be considered as a DoS vulnerability and worth reporting a CVE for that?

Comment: Just to be clear, the vulnerability is in your own app? It's really up to you to decide if it might be considered a DoS. I'm not sure if we can really answer that question for you - at least not based on the details provided.

Comment: If *you think* that it is a DoS, then it could be a DoS. As for CVE, is it a publicly distributed app? Do people need to host it themselves or are you hosting it?

Comment: If during the attack the server is unable to respond to legitimate client's requests, then it can be considered a DoS attack.